# Creating a custom dialog in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

How does one go about creating a custom dialog in wxPython? My intention is to create a dialog with 2 buttons called 'Gmail' and 'Outlook', instead of the 'OK' and 'CANCEL' or any other built-in options.

Does anyone know of a tutorial? Can this even be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can create your own custom Dialogs.

```
import wx
from wx.lib import sized_controls

ID_GMAIL = wx.NewId()
ID_OUTLOOK = wx.NewId()


class CustomDialog(sized_controls.SizedDialog):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomDialog, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        pane = self.GetContentsPane()

        static_line = wx.StaticLine(pane, style=wx.LI_HORIZONTAL)
        static_line.SetSizerProps(border=(('all', 0)), expand=True)

        pane_btns = sized_controls.SizedPanel(pane)
        pane_btns.SetSizerType('horizontal')
        pane_btns.SetSizerProps(align='center')

        button_ok = wx.Button(pane_btns, ID_GMAIL, label='Gmail')
        button_ok.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)

        button_ok = wx.Button(pane_btns, ID_OUTLOOK, label='Outlook')
        button_ok.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button)

        self.Fit()

    def on_button(self, event):
        if self.IsModal():
            self.EndModal(event.EventObject.Id)
        else:
            self.Close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    dlg = CustomDialog(None, title='Custom Dialog')
    result = dlg.ShowModal()
    if result == ID_GMAIL:
        print('Gmail')
    elif result == ID_OUTLOOK:
        print('Outlook')
    dlg.Destroy()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, I have some questions though. What does 'self.GetContentsPane()' do? Furthermore, when I try to implement this under an event, nothing happens. No GUI at all. :/ I'll add my code with it implemented as an EDIT:

Comment: Never mind the 'GUI not working' part of my question. Was a foolish mistake from my part. :)